# Trying to show this subset of $C[0,1]$ is open or closed.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to see if the set:

$$X =\{f\in{}C[0,1]:|f(t)|<1\text{ for all } t\in[0,1]\}$$ is open or closed.

If it is open at each function $g\in{}X$ there is an epsilon sized open ball around it contained by $X$. I can't seem to show that its open but can't think of a counter example to show its not.

Comment: Open/closed depends on the metric. What is the metric you are using on $C[0,1]$?

Comment: This is from an exercise set for practice on norms. This was all the information provided, I assume its supposed to be obvious the norm we should use. Would it seem sensible to use $\|f\|_{\infty}$?

Comment: $X=B(0,1)$ in $C[0,1],$ hence is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing the norm on  $C[0,1]$ is $\|f\| = \max_{t \in [0,1]} |f(t)|$, the corresponding metric on $C[0,1]$ is $d(f,g) = \|f-g\|$.

Select an element $f \in X$. Since $f$ attains its maximum at some point $t \in [0,1]$ you have $\|f\| < 1$. Let $\epsilon = 1 - \|f\|$.  Then, if $g \in B(f,\epsilon)$ you have
$$\|g\| \le \|f-g\| + \|f\| < \epsilon + \|f\| < 1$$ so that $g \in X$ too.

Comment: is the fact f attains its maximum due to the fact it is continuous?

Comment: @kam Yes, a function that's continuous on a closed interval also attains its maximum over that interval.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are working with the metric $(f,g)\mapsto\sup\lvert f-g\rvert$, consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\psi\colon&C[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&f&\mapsto&\sup\lvert f\rvert.\end{array}$$Then $\psi$ is continuous and $X=\psi^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,1)\bigr)$. Since the set $(-\infty,1)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$, $X$ is an open subset of $C[0,1]$.